# python item equivalent to another in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In python you can check if an item is in a list:

```
if item in lst:
   do_stuff()
```

However, how do I check if a LIKE item is in the list? The `is` operator checks for the actual object. The `in` operator does the same. Is there an equivalent operator of `==` for `in`?

What I want would be something like

```
if item is_equal_to_another_in lst:
    do_stuff()
```

For example: I have a list of `[item('a'), item('b'), item('c')]`. If I create another `item('a')` it will be exactly like the one in our list, except it will fail the `in` statement because the one in our list is a different instance.

Comment: That sounds like something you may have to do manually.

Comment: what is `item("a")`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham its just an example of creating an object

Comment: well if they were instances of a class you could have a name attribute then check `if any(item("a").name == x.name for x in items )` or whatever `a` represents

Comment: What makes you think `in` only uses `is` for comparisons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lists, `__contains__` just compares the object with the `__eq__` (`==`) operator. If not defined, it fall through to `is`.

You probably have to define `__eq__` for your specific definition of equality given your `items`.

---

In this example, I demonstrate how to compare two items based on the value of their `attr` attribute by performing a case insensitive comparison.

```
>>> class item:
...     def __init__(self,attr): self.attr = attr
...     def __eq__(self,o): return isinstance(o, item) and self.attr.lower() == o.attr.lower()
... 
>>> lst = [item("a"), item("b")]
>>> item("A") in lst
True
>>> item("a") in lst
True
>>> item("B") in lst
True
>>> item("C") in lst
False
>>> "A" in lst
False
```

Comment: but `c` is not in the list, the whole point is to have instances created with the same parameter be considered in the list

Comment: I think an actual example of how to use it properly would be a better answer